# Import error: "Ressource at URL not found" only for some specific stocks

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I'm creating a dividend tracker sheet in google sheets. I'm using following formula as I want to use some dividend data from yahoo finance

```
=SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(concatenate("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/";B8);"table";2);6;2);" ")
```

B8 is referring to the ticker from yahoo finance

It works well for all US stocks(Example: "T" and "JNJ") and for 1 EU stocks ("VOW3.DE").
For all other EU stocks (Ex: "SIE.DE") it doesn't work.
I'm using though the same formula

```
=SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(concatenate("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/";B5);"table";2);6;2);" ")
```

B5 refers to SIE.DE

I'm getting following error message:

> "#N/A": Error Ressource at url not found

Strange as it works well for VOW3.DE ticker (Volkswagen)

Answer (score 0):

This site is now built on client side by javascript, not on server side. Then you can't retrieve informations by importxml, neither importhtml. Hopefully, the page contains a big json called `root.App.main` that you can parse and retrieve data :

```
  var url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + code
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

for instance https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sTA71PhpxI_QdGKXVAtb0Rc3cmvPLgzvXKXXTmiec7k/copy

Comment: Thanks Mike for your answer. I have to point out that I'm able to retrieve via that same formula =SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(concatenate("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/";B8);"table";2);6;2);" ") dividend information for some stocks .so the problem is not that can't retrieve data. . I'm wondering why its not working for al other European stocks like Siemens (SIE.DE).

Comment: you're right, okay. I've spent a lot of time in the past figuring out how Yahoo now presents information, with javascript on and off. I compared the information in the raw source code on both sides and did not notice any significant deviations. I have definitely abandoned the classic functions in favor of json which is more reliable. But indeed, I cannot answer your question exactly.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your time and effort. Probably your solution is better but I have to admit that my Java programming skills are not good at all that I can use your idea it to retrieve dividend information.